# Delay issue 'Exec' child_process node js using powershell

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, powershell

This is not an issue but a question

This give me random execution delay

```
exec('echo aaa', { shell: 'powershell.exe' }, (err: any, stdout: any, stderr: any) => { 
...
```

And this not :

```
exec('powershell.exe echo aaa', { shell: 'cmd.exe' }, (err: any, stdout: any, stderr: any) => { 
...
```

I don't find any information about this 'problem' on internet, using exec method with powershell.

It seem to work using powershell on the head of command but if anyone have informations or explanation about this i would be delighted to understand.

Thank you :]

Comment: Here is my assumption, I am not sure if this is correct but here are my thoughts: PowerShell console usually takes a while to start up if you open up or call the executable since it loads the psprofile and other startup things to open the terminal which I assume is happening in example 1. In example 2 however, it is not actually openning and loading the terminal but rather just interpreting the command in PowerShell which saves the time of all of the startup things and loading the rest of the stuff in. The command you should be using is `powershell.exe -command "echo aaa"` though

Comment: Hi, i understand better, thank you for your explanation!